# datables is incompatible with laravel 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel-5, datatable, laravel-5.6

I'm doing a project with laravel 5.6 and I do not know if `datables` is incompatible with this version of the framework, because I have another system with laravel 5.4 and the `datable` works perfectly

But with this version I get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (list.js:3)
>       at i (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
>       at HTMLDocument.J (jquery.min.js:2)

I have the code exactly like in version 5.4 where it works

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <table id="table">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>CI</th>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Client</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach ($users as $user)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$user->ci}}</td>
                                <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$user->last_name}}</td>
                                <td>{{$user->position->CAR_DESCRI}}</td>
                                <td>{{$user->client->GTR_DESCRI}}</td>
                                <td><a href="{{ route('detailUser', ['user_id' => $user->ci]) }}"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">



 @section('js')
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/users/list.js') }}"></script>
    @endsection
```

I know that this error appears when I do not attach jquery, but here I do. What I can do?

in the file `list.js` is the call to the datable

File `list.js`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#table').DataTable({
        language: {
            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst":    "Primero",
                "sLast":     "Último",
                "sNext":     "Siguiente",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Make sure ‍‍`JQUERY` is loaded before all `js`  and test again.

Comment: code inside list.js?. On a side note, datatables works with 5.6 100% using it as we speak

Comment: I already included my list.js code

Comment: I already solved it, I think that since I was loading the `jquery` more than once it gave some kind of incompatibility